# Get Bluetooth input in windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth

I am working on a project that involved with Bluetooth headphones buttons.  I want to receive the Bluetooth signal from the headphone, and call a function, but what I found on the internet mostly work only in Linux, like the evdev module.  The platform I am using is Windows, so is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that Python on Windows for Bluetooth does not have great support and there is no obvious solution.

However, on Linux I don't think evdev would be the module to detect the button press on Bluetooth Headphones. These are normally covered by profiles like Hands Free profile (HFP), Headset profile (HSP), Cordless Telephony profile (CTP), or Intercom profile (ICP) which are covered in more detail on the Bluetooth SIG site:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/

The Windows Runtime Python Projection ([Python/WinRT](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/)) are intended to enable Python developers to access [Windows Runtime APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq) directly from Python. However I have not found any good examples to give guidance on how to use WinRT for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is a Keyboard event listener in windows and any device you attach with it, if it gives some input, then the program will automatically detect the corresponding keypress.

```
import keyboard  


while True:  
    try: 
        event = keyboard.read_event()
        event = str(event)
        final_username = event.replace("KeyboardEvent(", "")
        final_username = final_username[:-1]
        print(final_username)

    # your logic in between
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
        print('You Pressed A Key!')
        break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break
```